# Save Array to text in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, parsing

I've read a file from a text file and parsed the data I want, but I don't know how to save the parsed data in form to the file. Are you able to assist me? I've also included a snippet from the file.
https://ibb.co/G5hTtky --> link for the image

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\asr050322.txt");
        string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        
        string[] linesArray = text.Split("BOH");
            for (int i = 0; i < linesArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (linesArray[i].Substring(24, 5) == "UXOAP")
                {
                 File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\HeUXOAP050322.txt", Array.ConvertAll(linesArray[i], x => x.ToString()));
                }

                if (linesArray[i].Substring(24, 5) == "UXOGS")
                {
                 File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\UXOGS050322.txt", Array.ConvertAll(linesArray[i], x => x.ToString()));
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for File.AppendAll(Lines|Text) ...

Answer (score 2):

`File.WriteAllLines()` will overwrite an existing file, so as you loop, you will only keep the latest data.

Use `File.AppendText("path/to/file", linesArray[i]);`
This will create a file if it does not exist, then appends the data to the end of the existing file.

Comment: thank you very much, i did AppendAllText and it worked, and i have another question how do we prepend a string or a character to LinesArray[i]

Comment: as simple as `string line = "prefix_string" + linesArray[i]`. if you need to build a string with a lot of concats, replacing, etc, check out [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder)